Getting blank plots in Mathematica without any error message
I have encountered this problem quite often, and am equally puzzled each time, since there is never an error associated with it. Here with this code I get two plots at the end, which should be 3D plots, one of a wave profile and one of a probability density profile. However, both are blank. What is the reason for this?
Thanks
(* Define parameters *)
L = 10;                 (* Length of the domain in x *)
T = 50;                 (* Total time *)
dx = 0.08;              (* Spatial step size in x *)
dy = 0.08;              (* Spatial step size in y *)
dt = 0.001;             (* Time step size *)
xMax = L;               (* Maximum x value *)
yMax = L;               (* Maximum y value *)
xValues = Range[-L/2, L/2, dx];  (* Spatial grid in x *)
yValues = Range[-L/2, L/2, dy];  (* Spatial grid in y *)
mMax = Round[T/dt];     (* Maximum time index *)

(* Peregrine soliton initial condition *)
\[Psi]0[x_] := (1 - 4 (1 + 2 I x)/(1 + 4 x^2)) Exp[I x/5] + Sin[2 Pi x/5];

(* Initialize wave function in x-dimension *)
\[Psi] = Table[\[Psi]0[x], {x, xValues}];

(* Define the time evolution function *)
timeEvolution[\[Psi]_, m_] := Module[{\[Psi]New, nonlinearTerm, forceTerm},
    \[Psi]New = \[Psi];  (* Start with the current wave function *)
    (* Update wave function using FDM *)
    For[i = 2, i < Length[\[Psi]] - 1, i++,
        nonlinearTerm = Sqrt[2]*Abs[\[Psi][[i]]]^2 \[Psi][[i]];  (* Nonlinear term *)
        forceTerm = Sec[Pi*xValues[[i]]]^2;  (* Force term as Hyperbolic secant(x) *)
        \[Psi]New[[i]] = \[Psi][[i]] - (dt/(2 I)) (Pi*(\[Psi][[i + 1]] - 2 \[Psi][[i]] + \[Psi][[i - 1]])/(dx^2)) - dt nonlinearTerm + dt forceTerm;
    ];
    \[Psi]New
];

(* Store results for animation *)
results = {};
(* Time-stepping loop *)
For[m = 1, m <= mMax, m++,
    \[Psi] = timeEvolution[\[Psi], m];
    If[Mod[m, Round[mMax/5]] == 0, AppendTo[results, \[Psi]]];  (* Store every 5th wave function *)
];

(* Create 3D surface plot of the real part of the wave over x and y dimensions *)
ListAnimate[Table[
  ListPlot3D[Table[{xValues[[i]], y, Re[results[[m, i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[xValues]}, {y, yValues}],
             PlotRange -> All, 
             PlotLabel -> "NLSE with Force Term Secant(x) (3D Real Part)", 
             AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "Re[\[Psi](x,y,t)]"},
             Mesh -> None,
             ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
             ImageSize -> Large,
             PlotLegends -> {"t = " <> ToString[m dt]}],
  {m, 1, Length[results]}
]]

(* Create 3D surface plot of probability density |\[Psi](x,y,t)|^2 over x and y dimensions *)
ListAnimate[Table[
  ListPlot3D[Table[{xValues[[i]], y, Abs[results[[m, i]]]^2}, {i, 1, Length[xValues]}, {y, yValues}],
             PlotRange -> All, 
             PlotLabel -> "Probability Density |\[Psi](x,y,t)|^2 (3D)", 
             AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "|\[Psi](x,y,t)|^2"},
             Mesh -> None,
             ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
             ImageSize -> Large,
             PlotLegends -> {"t = " <> ToString[m dt]}],
  {m, 1, Length[results]}
]]


However, both are blank. What is the reason for this? one of the most common reasons for this, is that you are generating complex values. Did you look at sample of the output data to see if has complex number in it or not? Plot will not plot data with complex values. Need to use different commands or use Abs or Re or Im

But listplot3D has it, Abs[results[[m, i]]]^2} and Re[results[[m, i]]]

I think you need to Flatten your Table in ListPlot3D down 1 level:
Table[{xValues[[i]], y, Abs[results[[m, i]]]^2}, {i, 1,     Length[xValues]}, {y, yValues}] // Flatten[#, 1] &

Sorry, I did not look at your code in details. It could be a plot range issue then?. No time to look more now.

To improve performance, I changed the definition of timeEvolution to be more vector-like instead of using a For loop (also note that timeEvolution doesn't need the argument m):
timeEvolution[ψ_] := 
 Module[{ψNew, nonlinearTerm, forceTerm, addTerm},
  
  ψNew = ψ;
  nonlinearTerm = Sqrt[2]*Abs[ψ]^2 ψ;
  forceTerm = Sec[Pi*xValues]^2;
  
  addTerm = 
   dt forceTerm - dt nonlinearTerm + (
    I dt π (-2 ψ + RotateLeft[ψ] + 
       RotateRight[ψ]))/(2 dx^2);
  
  ψNew[[2 ;; -3]] += addTerm[[2 ;; -3]];
  ψNew
  ]

This does exactly what your old timeEvolution does, but instead of using a For[i = 2, i < Length[ψ] - 1,i++,...] loop to update ψ, it just directly acts on ψ[[2;;-3]] to update ψ (since those are the indices that the For loop would act on).

I also use Nest instead of a For loop to get the results (I call it resultsAll because I store every m in this case):
resultsAll = NestList[timeEvolution, ψ, mMax];


For plotting I'll show what I did for the last plot as an example.
First, notice that your results are independent of y, and only depend on x, so we can just look at the 2D projection instead of 3D (the wavefunction will be constant with y).
So we can just create our 2D data at the each time step we want to look at
animStepSize = Round[mMax/5];
results = resultsAll[[1 ;; All ;; animStepSize]];
absData = Thread[{xValues, Abs[#]^2}] & /@ results;

animTVals = Subdivide[T, 5];

And Animate:
Animate[ListLinePlot[absData[[i]], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "|\[Psi](x,y,t)|^2", "ball"}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    "Probability Density |\[Psi](x,y,t)|^2 (2D projection)", 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> Large] // 
  Labeled[#, "t = " <> ToString[Round@animTVals[[i]]]] &,
 {i, 1, Length@absData, 1}
 ]


